# Pros & Cons of using requirejs (-m amd) for typescript+angular projects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, require, amd

For an *angular* 1.x project that uses *typescript*, what are the Pros and Cons of using [*AMD*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition)?
Meaning, running `tsc` with the params `-m amd` and using *requirejs*, versus simply using the `/// <reference path="..." />` for internal modules as well and wrapping in `module`(s).

**Which-**

1. Makes more sense for *angularjs*? (if you think one is better than the other in this particular case).
2. Is better for large scale angular apps?
3. Would be better at *minification*+*obfuscation* of large code base?

Comment: I don't think using AMD to load angular modules does make any sense because angular 1.X does not support lazy loading of modules. So when you bootstrap your angular you have to load every module (with AMD or not!). You can use ocLazyLoad library but ocLazyLoad in combination with AMD module loading makes you code base very complex!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Makes more sense for angularjs?

Angular1 : `--module amd`
Angular2 : `--module system` as that is what *the angularjs team uses internally*.

> 2. Is better for large scale angular apps?

Yes. `--out` and `reference` comments *are a bad idea*. More : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

> 3. Would be better at minification+obfuscation of large code base?

It would be the same. The main advantage is dev time readability and maintainability.

Comment: According to the `tsc` command, there's no such thing as `--module system`, I ran `tsc --module system main.ts` and got
`error TS6046: Argument for '--module' option must be 'commonjs' or 'amd'.`

Comment: You need to use the *latest* version of TypeScript.

Comment: I use Version 1.5.0-beta, there is no newer version in npm.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out, but if it's only in snapshots, are you sure it would still be good for a production app? also, any references to angular team's usage of this? I know angular2 uses SystemJS, but it's not the same with angular 1.x

Comment: Also, I didn't find any documentation on `--module system` for typescript while googling.

Comment: Sorry. didn't notice angular 1.x. Use amd. Updated answer. Angular 2 team is using snapshots as well btw ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80539/discussion-between-alon-amir-and-basarat).